# Signing transaction with Metamask (not sending)

Tags: web3js, transactions, metamask

I use the following code to sign and send a transaction in my backend:

```
var txData = {
    nonce: nonceHex,
    gasPrice: gasPriceHex,
    gas: gasHex,
    data: contractData,
    from: ctx.mainAccount,
};

var tx = new EthTx(txData);
tx.sign(new Buffer(pKey, 'hex'));
var txHex = tx.serialize().toString('hex');

web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(`0x${txHex}`)
    .on('receipt', receipt => { ... });
```

Now what I'd like to do is instead of using the private key here, **I'd like to use Metamask just to sign the transaction (and not send it)**

Is it possible? In other words does Metamask has a way to do something similar to `tx.sign(new Buffer(pKey, 'hex'));` I'd like then my backend to  send the signed transaction, not Metamask.

I tried to use web3.eth.personal like this:

```
//backend
var tx = new EthTx(txData);
var txHash = tx.hash();
var txUnsignedHex = txHash.toString('hex');

//browser
web3.personal.sign('0x' + txUnsignedHex, ethAccount, (err, result) => {  ... } );
```

But the result I get does not work when I run web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction

Answer (score 3):

MetaMask does not currently support signing but not submitting a transaction, although the idea has been suggested before:

https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/2506

You could share your use case there, to help it gain priority.